# RPi will not boot to command line

Tags: pi-2, boot, raspbian-jessie

My RPi 2 (jessie) still boots to desktop, if I configure CLI in raspi-config.
I also tried what was recommended [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=95724):

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
sudo ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

But this did not change anything, it still boost in desktop mode.
I also tried what was proposed in one of the answers to disable and mask the lightdm:

```
sudo systemctl status lightdm -l
```

```
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; static)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-08-28 21:42:31 CEST; 4min 42s ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
 Main PID: 661 (lightdm)
   CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
           ├─661 /usr/sbin/lightdm
           └─754 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch

Aug 28 21:42:31 raspberrypi lightdm[661]: ** (lightdm:661): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
Aug 28 21:42:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Aug 28 21:42:33 raspberrypi lightdm[661]: ** (process:951): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
Aug 28 21:42:33 raspberrypi lightdm[951]: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
```

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm
```

```
Synchronizing state for lightdm.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d lightdm defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d lightdm disable
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `lightdm' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `lightdm' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

```
sudo systemctl mask lightdm
```

```
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/lightdm.service to /dev/null.
```

A subsequent status request gives the same result as above.

Comment: what was the result of trying to run `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Comment: did you also do `ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` ... both of these should be executed using `sudo` of course (or in a root terminal session)

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes, I executed both commands using sudo, and they executed without error. But the result was that the system still boots into desktop mode.

Comment: Can somebody please tell me why this questions is closed?

Comment: You are asking an obscure question about an obsolete OS for starters and have provided no meaningful details.

Comment: Raspbian Jessie isn't supported anymore since 2020-01-01 and its repository is archived. You should use an up to date [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/).

Comment: @Ingo: I tried to upgrade, but no success. I finally ended up with a fresh install of Raspberry PI OS.

Answer (score 1):

Check:

```
systemctl status lightdm
```

It's probably running (lightdm is the GUI login, 'dm' = display manager). Change that:

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm
sudo systemctl mask lightdm
```

Running both of them may be redundant but it won't hurt (see `man systemctl` for the difference).

You can then check `systemctl status lightdm`; it will still be running but the fact that it is disabled/masked indicated.

Then reboot.  I've done stuff much like this before and never had problems but there is the off-chance the system will get temporarily borked, leave a comment here if that happens and we can sort it out.

Comment: I tried it, but no success. It still boots do desktop. I edited the question, because a comment is too short to cover the output.